# Checkbox filter/search button: can't undo filtering when unchecked

Tags: javascript, search, checkbox, datatables, toggle

I have a table made with datatables. There is checkbox, which, when clicked filters  the table to display only the data I want to see. The problem is that when I uncheck the checkbox, the table becomes buggy. The table.destroy() function does seemingly revert the table back to the way it was, although it looks like it destroys a little too much (rows per page suddenly get ignored + can no longer click on cell, which opens up in another window). I'm guessing destroy() is not the correct way to revert back to the original table/data when unchecked. So what is the correct way?

This is what happens:

1. click on checkbox: filters the data correctly
2. uncheck checkbox: table looks as if gone back to normal (but hasn't really)
3. check checkbox again: no longer filters data correctly. (table is now empty)
4. now it doesn't matter if I check or uncheck, the table stays the same(empty)

Here is my code:

```
var checkbox = $("#checkB");
checkbox.click(function () {
     var table = $('#TABLE_NAME').DataTable();
     if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                    var num = Number(data[4]);
                    if (num > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            );
            table.draw();
        }
    else {
            table.destroy();    
        }
    });
```

Comment: quick edit: I've noticed when using breakpoints that right after going through the "table.destroy();" part, it then tries goes back and reads through "var num = Number(data[4]);" etc. How is that even possible given that that code is within "if (checkbox.is(":checked"))" . The code is reading through within that code even though the checkbox isn't checked.... so confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. in the 'Else' part, I just wrote:

```
else {
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
            table.draw();
        }
```

et voila!

Answer (score 0):

**This is it!** I figure out the problem. Here is the final working code.

**Hint:** I hack around the filter function

```js
var checkbox = $("#checkB");
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
  function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
      if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
        return Number(data[1]) > 0 ? true : false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }
);

checkbox.click(function () {
  if (checkbox.is(":checked")) {
    table.draw();
  } else {
    table.draw();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkB" value="Check"> Check this to filter
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Example</th>
            <th>Number</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Example1</td>
            <td>-10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example2</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Example3</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately neither clear() nor destroy() worked in your code. clear() broke the working data filter and destroy() in that position literally made the whole table vanish completely after unchecking the box.

Comment: I update the comment, It might help you a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to get it to work but no luck. I cannot reinitialize it like this: table.rows.add([
      ['Example1','50'],
      ['Example2','10'],
      ['Example3','20'],
    ]).draw(); because I am using AJAX to get the data from a sql database

Comment: I have updated my original post to show where my data is coming from.

Comment: Oh, your data is in ajax. You might look into ajax.reload() function. https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()

Comment: I've tried adding that to the 'else' part after destroying/clearing the table. I get this error on the ajax.reloaded() line: Unable to set property 'data' of undefined or null reference. Maybe it needs some callback parameter.